# Getting exception while running the reporting database rebuild tool

Tags: sql-database, reporting

I am trying to rebuild the reporting database using the URL, https://abc.com/sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx but every time getting the below error.
[image]

The version of Sitecore we are using is 9.0.2, also connection string of reporting and reporting.secondary databases are correctly configured in the CMS server config file.

Thanks
Nash

Comment: Try to update the reporting, reporting.secondary and  xdb.processing.tasks connection strings by adding:
;Connection Timeout=90;

Comment: Still getting the same error what I was getting earlier.

Comment: @Nash can you try to use DTC Tester to see if there are any issues with the configuration. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30746

Comment: could you please share your configuration changes and the `aggregation/reportingStoragaProviders` section for secondary?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat : Which all configs you need and from which server, like we have separate CM, Processing, and Xconnect server. Also "aggregation/reportingStoragaProviders section for secondary" this part from which file?

Comment: You could try this hotfix https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/224364